# Edit Fan Page Icon

Tags: facebook

I am need to add facebook fan page icon image by myself uploading some image for that icon. Is it possible. Is is possible to add using Facebook API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create the fan page yourself? If so, you just simply upload an image to change the profile picture much like you would for your personal page.